# replace first semicolon occurence

Tags: sed, regular-expression, tr

Hi I have a logfile and I want to replace the first semicolon occurence, like:

```
head1;head2;head3;head4;head5 
blabb;blabl;;blab;blabl;;bla
```

Desired output:

```
 head1;head2;head3;head4;head5 
 blabb;blabl;blab;blabl;;bla
```

With regular expression how can select the first occurrence and replace for ";"
I have the next command in sed:

```
sed -i 's/;;/;/g'
```

but this one replace all the occurrences file. Is there another way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the substitution only act once, remove the `/g` modifier:

```
s/;;/;/
```